# Occurrences in 2D array from 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Recently I've come into a wall, because I have no idea how to count the occurrences in one 2d array from another 2d array. For example, if I have

```
int winning_nums[3][6]; // random generated numbers array
```

and

```
int array[7][7]; // Sorted array from 1 to 49
```

I need to get all occurrences of each number in `winning_nums` to all the elements in `array`.For example: If I got 1 array of `winning_nums` that equals 6 size, 1 2 3 4 5 6 needs to be checked if they are occuring in `array`, like for each row in `winning_nums`.

I've tried to sort it out, like sort the `winning_nums` array, and then try to occur it with two additional `for` loops.

Any better ideas? Anything is welcomed.

Comment: So you want to compare 3 combinations of 6 numbers with 7 combinations of 7 numbers? Sorry but your task description should be improved.

Comment: If your code works, you may want to post to [codereview.se].